# When does magnification not depend on distance of object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Two thin lenses share a common optical axis. Their focal lengths are f1 = 20 cm, respectively and f2=50 cm. In front of the first lens at distance x>f1 there is an item. On the screen behind the second lens at a certain distance adjusted to x a real image of the object is created. It turns out that regardless of x the image on the screen is always the same size, regardless of the position of the object. How much is d? - distance between lenses?

I tried using the lens formulas, but this didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem. Both are based in the equations for the [magnification of a single lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification#Single_lens), and [the effective focal length of two lenses](https://jackwestin.com/resources/mcat-content/geometrical-optics/combination-of-lenses):

$M = \frac{1}{1-x/f}$

$\frac{1}{f_{2L}} = \frac{1}{f_1} + \frac{1}{f_2} - \frac{d}{f_1 f_2}$

In both cases the solution is a telescope: $ d=f_1+f_2 $

### Solution 1:

The magnification is insensitive of $x$ only in the limit when $1/f \rightarrow 0$. For this to happen, the second equation above should be $0$. Solve it for $d$.

### Solution 2:

Substitute the equation for the effective focal length into the equation for the magnification, then take the derivative wrt. $x$ and set it to $0$. Again solve for $d$